# How to remove eslint Parsing error on ES6 export statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, lint

npm `v3.10.10` node `v6.11.0` eslint `v4.2.0`

You can pull **[the repo here](https://github.com/leongaban/Duckr)**. Just `npm install` then `npm run lint`

I'm trying to use the following export statement (comment works, but is ugly):

#### containers/index.js

```
export MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer'
// export { default as MainContainer } from './Main/MainContainer'
```

#### config/routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, HashRouter, browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { MainContainer } from '../containers'

const routes = (
  <HashRouter history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={MainContainer} />
  </HashRouter>
)

export default routes
```

---

I installed the following package:

`npm install babel-eslint@next --save-dev`

#### .eslintrc

```
{
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  en: {
    es6: true,
    browser: true
  },
  extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "standard"],
  plugins: [
    "react"
  ]
}
```

#### .eslintrc.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            2
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "off",
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```

However even with that installed I still get the error about the MainContainer when I `npm run lint`

[image]

#### package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server",
  "production": "webpack -p",
  "lint": "eslint app/.; exit 0",
  "fix": "eslint --fix app/.; exit 0"
},

"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^8.0.0-alpha.13",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
  "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
  "eslint": "^4.2.0",
  "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
  "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.5.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
  "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
  "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
  "webpack": "^3.2.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
}
```

#### folder structure

[image]

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares just added them!

Comment: You need to do an import on your index.js file. import MainContainer from */your file path here/*

Comment: @yoursweater I have that line in my routes.js `import { MainContainer } from '../containers'`

Comment: @LeonGaban I think that you need babel plugin `stage-1` or just `babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions` - https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-export-extensions/. Bear in mind that you should add this plugin to the `.babelrc`. This syntax is not yet official.

Comment: You'll need a valid export statement. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export.

Comment: https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-more-export-from

Comment: I added the link to the repo https://github.com/leongaban/Duckr You can check it out locally!

Comment: @hinok Hi, so still having a problem with the fancy export of MainContainer, will post a new question then link you. The `stage-1` did not work.

Comment: @hinok here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090484/eslint-parsing-error-on-export-statement would you mind a look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out! I needed to edit my .eslintrc.json file, not the .eslintrc

https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/6

```
{
...
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
...
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!