# ESLint parsing error on Export statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, eslint

I'm following a course and the author exports out a Component in the following manner:

`export MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer'`

The default correct way is `export { default as MainContainer } from './Main/MainContainer'` which is not as clean. The author is able to do this with a babel-eslint package, however after I installed that package I still get the lint error.

**[Repo link](https://github.com/leongaban/Duckr)**

File structure:

[image]

### Expected

No ESlint errors when using `export MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer'` in containers/index.js. That export statement should allow config/routes.js to import the MainContainer like so:

`import { MainContainer } from '../containers'`

### Results

ESlint error:

[image]

---

containers/Main/MainContainer.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default class MainContainer extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <p>Hello World</p>
    )
  }
}
```

containers/index.js

```
export MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer'
// export { default as MainContainer } from './Main/MainContainer'
```

config/routes.js

```
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import routes from './config/routes'

ReactDom.render(
  routes,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

I have the following packages installed:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^8.0.0-alpha.15",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
  "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
  "eslint": "^4.2.0",
  "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
  "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.5.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
  "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
  "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
  "webpack": "^3.2.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
}
```

The npm run lint script:

```
"lint": "eslint app/.; exit 0",
```

.babelrc

```
{
  presets: [
    'react',
    'es2015',
    'stage-0',
    'stage-1'
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-export-extensions"]
}
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  env: {
    es6: true,
    browser: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 6,
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
      experimentalObjectRestSpread: true
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    "react",
  ],
  extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "standard"],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": [2, {allow: ["warn", "error"]}],
    "comma-dangle" : [2, "always-multiline"],
    "semi": [2, "never"],
    "no-extra-semi": 2,
    "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-single"],
    "react/jsx-boolean-value": [2, "always"],
    "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": [2, {selfClosing: "after-props", nonEmpty: "after-props"}],
    "react/jsx-curly-spacing": [2, "never", {"allowMultiline": false}],
    "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": [2, {maximum: 3}],
    "react/jsx-no-literals": 2,
    "react/self-closing-comp": 2,
    "react/sort-comp": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my app when I did `eslint --init` I choose `json` as one of the options.

This created a `.eslint.json` file, so I had 2 eslint files, my original `.eslintrc` and the json version.

I believe the `.json` version was overriding the non-JSON version.

Here is the file with the additions from the original:

[image]

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-console": [2, {"allow": ["warn", "error"]}],
      "indent": ["error", 2],
      "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
      "quotes": ["error","single"],
      "semi": [2,"never"],
      "no-extra-semi": 2,
      "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-single"],
      "react/jsx-boolean-value": [2, "always"],
      "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": [
        2, {"selfClosing": "after-props", "nonEmpty": "after-props"}
      ],
      "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": [2, {"maximum": 3}],
      "react/self-closing-comp": 2,
      "react/sort-comp": 2
    }
}
```

Now I do not get the error or warning when using:

`export MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer'`

Answer (score 2):

> The default correct way is export { default as MainContainer } from './Main/MainContainer'

Where did you get that information? According to the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), you could either:

```
export { MainContainer as default } from './Main/MainContainer'
```

or

```
export default MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer'
```

Comment: From the TylerMcginnis course, the app works, it's just the ESlint. I just figured out the problem. Posting my own answer, will wait on feed back.